# Provider hosted app ERROR:"delopyment not performed.."

Tags: office-365, deployment, provider-hosted-app

I am new to Provider Hosted apps, I have just created a small application for Provider Hosted App by follwing the steps on msdn [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx) I have successfully built the application with no errors however when I try to deploy it with [these](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-approach-to-create-a-Provider-Hosted-Application-in-SharePoint-2013) steps for I am encounter an error which says.

> Deployment was not performed for [AppName] because it is a provider-hosted app for SharePoint.

can anyone help me provide me a solution over this, I am not able to find any context related to this error

Comment: Have you used Azure for web application hosting? Have you implemented remote event receiver or AppEventReceiver?

Comment: No i am trying to host it on my IIS

Comment: Hi @akshay I am also facing this error. Can you please assist me on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

We have to create **High Trust** SharePoint app, that are only be installed in **SharePoint on-premise**. A high-trust app uses digital certificates to establish a trust between the remote web application and SharePoint 2013.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179901.aspx) you can get some reference for high-trust SharePoint app. It shows whole procedures for making self-signed digital certificates for trust between the remote web application and SharePoint 2013.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860570.aspx) you can get some reference for packaging and publishing of high-trust apps for SharePoint 2013.

Useful reference:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shariq/archive/2013/05/07/how-to-set-up-high-trust-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-amp-troubleshooting-tips.aspx

Please refer these links and if you have some problem then inform me.